# ERROR TypeError: filter[this.selectedSearch] is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have a function like this:It is for filtering items

```
searchFor() {
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code in stackbiltz

Answer (score 1):

This `filter[this.selectedSearch]();` is not a valid function call.. it's clearly syntax error

you might need to change your code to

```
filter(this.selectedSearch);
```

hope this helps.. :)

Comment: ah, if I do this:  filter(filters.Registratie); it works

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is not correct, I can see that filter is a function not object, so you can do `filter(value)` instead of `filter[value]()`

Answer (score 0):

So this is the trick:

```
   filter(filters[this.selectedSearch]);
```